# Can't get IntelliJ to download Maven dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get Apache Log4j 2.9.0 into my IntelliJ Maven project, but am getting nowhere.  This is the first time I've tried to use Maven with IntelliJ; I've been able to use it successfully with Eclipse in the past.  (I'm using Windows 10 if it makes a difference.)

What I've tried:

1) In pom.xml, Alt+Insert -> Dependency, search for an artifact with log4j.  It will find log4j 1.x, but not log4j-api or log4j-core which are needed for 2.x.

2) Downloaded log4j 2.9.0 from Apache.  Their web site didn't tell me what to do with the file; after unzipping the download, I copied the top-level folder to .m2\repository.  Retried searching for log4j, but it still couldn't find log4j 2.x stuff; tried various things like "Reimport all Maven projects", the Update button on the Settings page for Maven, Invalidate all caches and restart.... nothing has worked.

**Edit:** When I typed the above, I was sure there was a pom.xml file in my download.  But I just double-checked and there wasn't.  So I don't know whether any of the downloads on the Apache web page will work for Maven.

3) On the Settings page for Maven Repositories, tried "Test" on all the "Artifactory or Nexus Service URLs".  The Test seemed to work fine.

4) On the Maven Settings page, changed Maven Home Directory from Bundled (Maven 3) to something inside Program Files (x86)\Jet Brains, which showed up on the drop-down menu.  Didn't help.

I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.1.1, build #IC-145.597, Maven 3.0.5.

I must be missing a setting, but I can't figure out what.  The documentation at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html isn't helpful for solving this.

Comment: try running it in the command line? `mvn clean install`. It works for me in the commandline. Once it installed all the required depenencies into my local .m2, intelliJ is happy. I have not bother to see why but I guess it might be something to do with setting up proxy in the IDE.

Comment: @MinhKieu What directory do I have to be in to run it?  Do I need to `cd .m2\repository`?

Comment: No. In the same directory of your project where pom.xml live.

Comment: @MinhKieu OK, I was sure there was one, but there isn't... I'll see if there's another place to download from.  But in Eclipse, I think it was able to download the stuff it needed itself.

Comment: weird. Is this not a maven project? In your description above, you said `...in the pom.xml`?. If it is a true maven project, the pom.xml will live in the root directory of the project...Its the in the pom.xml that controls which dependencies needed to download and use.

Comment: It should be a Maven project.  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html shows what artifacts are needed.  (BTW, I copied the dependencies from that website into my pom.xml, but IntelliJ just complains that they can't be found.)  I think that the download page I found earlier might not be set up for downloading Maven projects.

Comment: You can manually create the pom.xml and import the project into Intellij? You should be able to compile and build from the commandline as well as using the IDE. Are you also new to Maven?

Comment: I've used Maven for small Eclipse projects, but mostly just to add dependencies, mostly just by following instructions and pushing the right buttons.  I was assuming I could do things the same way with IntelliJ, and that I wouldn't have to become a Maven expert just to use log4j.  I haven't delved into how it all works, so in that sense you could say I'm new to it.

Comment: Its not difficult if you already got the basic. You need to understand how it works in the commandline then troubleshoot why the IDE is not working. As I said, if its a true maven project then the pom.xml will be in the root of the project or module. There you define which dependencies you want your project to use. Once its successfully built from the commandline with `mvn clean install` then import it into IntelliJ and go ffrom there. If you have setup maven correctly then the repos settings will be in the $home/.m2 folder. Run the above command and see what errors are you seeing.

Comment: I think that my attempt to download log4j directly was a distraction--I downloaded something that wasn't intended for use with Maven.  I tried to Google for a way to download log4j, and I found the wrong one.  But log4j 2.9.0 is clearly able to be imported as a Maven dependency; I just tried it with Eclipse and it worked, and it's listed in [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.9.0).  So there should be some way to bring it in through IntelliJ--without needing to fool around hacking on the wrong download.

Comment: This is strange... I just tried it again, and now it's working.  I'm able to get both log4j-api and log4j-core 2.9.0.  I don't know whether there was a problem accessing one of the repos, or IntelliJ had to download something in the background that took a long time, or what.  Voting to close my own question as not reproducible.

Comment: OK, I can't say it's really working.  I don't see errors on my project's pom.xml before, as I did previously.  But it still can't find the Java packages.   [It looks like they've had some problems with Maven.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207108385-IntelliJ-not-able-to-resolve-classes-of-external-Libraries-for-Maven-projects)

Comment: good one! All the best!